# Ant not using my JAVA_HOME to find tools.jar

Tags: java, linux, ant, rpm

I realize that this question is going to initially sound like a duplicate of some other questions, but none of the other questions I've looked at fixed my issue.

The short story is that I have a JRE and a JDK installed at different locations. I set `JAVA_HOME` to point to the JDK, yet ant seems to still search for `tools.jar` in the JRE location. I'm not sure if this has more to do with my ant installation/configuration, or my JDK installation/configuration.

Here's the long story:

## Environment

I am running on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.5 (Maipo) on an account that does not have sudo privileges to anything.

## My JDK install

The machine already has the JRE installed at `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-7.b10.el7.x86_64/jre/bin/java`. I am not allowed to modify that install, but I can create my own java installation in a separate location.

The security requirements on my network are very stringent and I am only allowed to put specific pieces of software on the machine. It is possible to ask permission for other pieces of software, but I have to go through an approval process that is a huge pain. I have obtained permission to put JDK 1.8 from openJDK on the machine.

Since openJDK does not release tar balls of the whole installation and since I don't have sudo permissions I attempted to install the JDK by downloading `java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.172-13.b11.fc29.x86_64.rpm` and `java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.172-13.b11.fc29.x86_64.rpm` to `/local/apps/openJDK8` and running (from `/local/apps/openJDK8`)

```
rpm2cpio < java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.172-13.b11.fc29.x86_64.rpm | cpio -i --make-directories
rpm2cpio < java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.172-13.b11.fc29.x86_64.rpm | cpio -i --make-directories
```

For some reason this doesn't seem to do a complete JDK install (I think I must be missing some dependencies). I discovered that libjava.so, libjvm.so, jvm.cfg, and the server folder were missing, so I just created some links to the JRE install that had them (run from `local/apps/openJDK8`):

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-7.b10.el7.x86_64/lib/amd64/jvm.cfg usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.172-13.b11.fc29.x86_64/lib/amd64/jvm.cfg
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-7.b10.el7.x86_64/lib/amd64/libjava.so usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.172-13.b11.fc29.x86_64/lib/amd64/libjava.so
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-7.b10.el7.x86_64/lib/amd64/libjvm.so usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.172-13.b11.fc29.x86_64/lib/amd64/libjvm.so
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-7.b10.el7.x86_64/lib/amd64/server usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.172-13.b11.fc29.x86_64/lib/amd64/server
```

That step makes me a little nervous, so it could be part of my problem. At any rate, javac and java seem to work fine.

## ANT INSTALL

For my ant installation, I just downloaded a tar ball and extracted it to `/local/apps/ant` and then did:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/local/apps/openJDK8/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.172-13.b11.fc29.x86_64
export ANT_HOME=/local/apps/ant/apache-ant-1.10.4
```

I didn't bother updating the path because for now I'm just using fully qualified paths for everything. My ultimate goal is to have Jenkins running all of this anyway and it just uses fully qualified paths.

## Results

Now if I try to run ant, I get:

```
> /local/apps/ant/apache-ant-1.10.4/bin/ant
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-7.b10.el7.x86_64/lib/tools.jar
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

The `build.xml does not exist` part is of course expected, but the inability to locate `tools.jar` needs to be resolved. The strangest part for me is that according to the error message, it is actually looking for it in the JRE installation location.

Since `ant` itself is just a shell script, I modified it to print out a little more information by adding the following lines to the end of the file so that it looks like:

```
echo Running $ant_exec_command $ant_exec_args
echo JAVA_HOME = $JAVA_HOME
echo JAVACMD = $JAVACMD
echo CLASSPATH = $CLASSPATH
echo LOCALCLASSPATH = $LOCALCLASSPATH
echo ANT_HOME = $ANT_HOME
echo ANT_LIB = $ANT_LIB
eval "$ant_exec_command $ant_exec_args"
```

Now the output is:

```
$ /local/apps/ant/apache-ant-1.10.4/bin/ant
JAVA_HOME is /local/apps/openJDK8/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.172-13.b11.fc29.x86_64
Running exec "$JAVACMD" -classpath "$LOCALCLASSPATH" -Dant.home="$ANT_HOME" -Dant.library.dir="$ANT_LIB" org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher -cp "$CLASSPATH"
JAVA_HOME = /local/apps/openJDK8/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.172-13.b11.fc29.x86_64
JAVACMD = /local/apps/openJDK8/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.172-13.b11.fc29.x86_64/bin/java
CLASSPATH =
LOCALCLASSPATH = /local/apps/ant/apache-ant-1.10.4/lib/ant-launcher.jar
ANT_HOME = /local/apps/ant/apache-ant-1.10.4
ANT_LIB = /local/apps/ant/apache-ant-1.10.4/lib
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-7.b10.el7.x86_64/lib/tools.jar
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

So `JAVA_HOME` is clearly set. I can even verify further that ant is actually using the `JAVA_HOME` value that I set for at least some things because if I remove all of those links I created in my JDK install, it will complain that it can't find `libjava.so`.

So ant is clearly using my JDK install for at least a little bit, but still looking in the old JRE install for `tools.jar`.

Any ideas on what is going on?

Comment: What's the output of `ls /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-7.b10.el7.x86_64/lib` ?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the system provided JDK?  It looks like it's a very minor version behind the latest you've got, and unless you're getting bit by whatever bug that minor release fixed, I wouldn't worry about installing my own.

Comment: @David, the system provided java install is actually just a JRE, not a JDK. It's a little confusing because it has "openJDK" in the name, but it is just the JRE that is produced by openJDK.

Comment: @CAustin, there is no `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-7.b10.el7.x86_64/lib`. The only folder inside `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-7.b10.el7.x86_64/` is `jre`. That's because the existing install is a JRE only and not JDK (see above response to David's comment).

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out :)

This fix still feels a little more like a workaround than an actual fix, so if someone else has a better solution, I'd be interested to hear it.

I've browsed through the ant source code a bit and discovered that ant has a `--launchdiag` property which is helpful. Running with that gave me:

```
/local/apps/openJDK8/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.172-13.b11.fc29.x86_64/bin/java -classpath /local/apps/ant/apache-ant-1.10.4/lib/ant-launcher.jar -Dant.home=/local/apps/ant/apache-ant-1.10.4 -Dant.library.dir=/local/apps/ant/apache-ant-1.10.4/lib org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher --launchdiag
Launcher JAR= "/local/apps/ant/apache-ant-1.10.4/lib/ant-launcher.jar"
Launcher JAR directory= "/local/apps/ant/apache-ant-1.10.4/lib"
java.home= "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-7.b10.el7.x86_64/jre"
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-7.b10.el7.x86_64/lib/tools.jar
tools.jar= "null"
Setting "java.class.path" to "/local/apps/ant/apache-ant-1.10.4/lib/ant-launcher.jar:/local/apps/ant/apache-ant-1.10.4/lib/ant-antlr.jar:/local/apps/ant/apache-ant-1.10.4/lib/ant-swing.jar:/local/apps/ant/apache-ant-1.10.4/lib/ant-testutil.jar:/local/apps/ant/apache-ant-1.10.4/lib/ant-apache-xalan2.jar:/local/apps/ant/apache-ant-1.10.4/lib/ant-junitlauncher.jar:/local/apps/ant/apache-ant-1.10.4/lib/ant-xz.jar:/local/apps/ant/apache-ant-1.10.4/lib/ant-junit.jar:/local/apps/ant/apache-ant-1.10.4/lib/ant.jar:/local/apps/ant/apache-ant-1.10.4/lib/ant-apache-log4j.jar:/local/apps/ant/apache-ant-1.10.4/lib/ant-javamail.jar:/local/apps/ant/apache-ant-1.10.4/lib/ant-apache-bsf.jar:/local/apps/ant/apache-ant-1.10.4/lib/ant-apache-resolver.jar:/local/apps/ant/apache-ant-1.10.4/lib/ant-apache-oro.jar:/local/apps/ant/apache-ant-1.10.4/lib/ant-apache-bcel.jar:/local/apps/ant/apache-ant-1.10.4/lib/ant-jai.jar:/local/apps/ant/apache-ant-1.10.4/lib/ant-jsch.jar:/local/apps/ant/apache-ant-1.10.4/lib/ant-jmf.jar:/local/apps/ant/apache-ant-1.10.4/lib/ant-commons-logging.jar:/local/apps/ant/apache-ant-1.10.4/lib/ant-launcher.jar:/local/apps/ant/apache-ant-1.10.4/lib/ant-jdepend.jar:/local/apps/ant/apache-ant-1.10.4/lib/ant-commons-net.jar:/local/apps/ant/apache-ant-1.10.4/lib/ant-netrexx.jar:/local/apps/ant/apache-ant-1.10.4/lib/ant-junit4.jar:/local/apps/ant/apache-ant-1.10.4/lib/ant-apache-regexp.jar"
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

In the code I found that that `java.home` property comes from `System.getProperty("java.home")` which apparently is not the same thing as `JAVA_HOME`

By adding `-Djava.home=$JAVA_HOME` I was able to get it working